# Should you first remove valves and check them before removing turbocharger if getting overboost error in VW Tiguan 2009?

Tags: turbocharger, tiguan

Based on comment from this question: [How to fix overboost for VW Tiguan 2009?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/88469/how-to-fix-overboost-for-vw-tiguan-2009)

> You may be able to remove and inspect the two valves without taking
> the entire turbo assy. out.

So did the shop do wrong thing economically by removing whole turbocharger without removing and checking valves when there is overboost error?

Or it is possilbe to remove valves but not much difference in cost of worktime from just removing turbocharger at the same time and check everything? And maybe it is even more worth to remove everything at once?

Comment: Did this happen to your vehicle? I personally would think it is a matter of preference as it would be much easier to check and work on the turbo outside of the vehicle than it would in the vehicle. This is my own personal opinion, though.

Comment: Yes, my vehicle has a problem. Oh, ok so looks like shop did ok by removing turbocharger, since it also checked the turbocharger. Thanks