# How to check VW Tiguan 2009 turbocharger valves if they are good?

Tags: turbocharger, tiguan

Based on this: [How to fix overboost for VW Tiguan 2009?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/88469/how-to-fix-overboost-for-vw-tiguan-2009)

The service said that the air is controlled electronically in the turbine. And because of electronic failure, I might be getting the overboost error. Is that true? I watched this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pn-uCAgB4H8&ab_channel=EngineeringExplained and there it shows that this is controlled using spring. Maybe in tiguan is different.

If they are controlled electronically - then how they are checked? Need to attach to the turbocharger?

Comment: I believe you asked a very similar question already and appear to have abandoned it.  but the video is a general explanation of how turbocharging works and you're trying to use it as a specific troubleshooting guide for your vehicle.

Comment: From the similar questions I did not get enought information, I am not sure what to do